# Simulating LAN computers

Tags: c#, simulation, lan

How can I test a C# multiplayer(4 players) LAN game.Rather than connecting 4 computers can I simulate 4 different computers(run the application with different IPs. i.e four instances of the application).I considered to do with four virtual machines but can't run four virtual machines.(h/w resources :(

Comment: Why cant you just connect the apps together? Why do they need different IPs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not run all instances on the same machine but just on different ports?

Answer (score 3):

If you are **not** using multicast, then just have them on the same computer, but have the clients listen on different ports (only one listener per port is permitted).

If you **are** using multicast, you have a few options

- Broadcast your data to multiple multicast addresses in debug mode, so you can have the clients on the same host OS and machine.
- If you are running Linux, you could try to run them in something like OpenVZ to separate the different clients.
- If you have multiple NICs, use them!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you can run only one instance of the game per PC.

So... you could load up 4 virtual instance of the operating system with different ports assigned to each, and then load one game instance up inside each virtual OS.

There are a few of these products out there, but here are two of them.

http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/

(probably vmware bought out the other company I was thinking of as I can't find them).

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/